# What mean たまらない in this sentence

Tags: words

After giving a ride to a girl, a character says: 放課後 迎えに来っからよ

Then the girl says: 冗談！ お顔と相談ね！ ちょっとバイクに 乗せてもらったからってたまりませんわ！

I didn't understand the meaning of the たまりません. Could you explain me?

お返事、ありがとうございます

Answer (score 1):

たまらない (or たまらん, たまんねー, etc.; literally "won't stay") is a fixed way to say either of:

- it's so bad that I cannot bear it; no way; unbearable; unreasonable; overwhelmed
- it's so cool that I cannot hold it; irresistible

As always, the meaning depends on the context. In your situation, it's used in the former sense. She's saying dating her after school is out of the question and she is amazed/overwhelmed by such an unreasonable suggestion. (By the way, this せんわ is a Kansai-ben sentence ender. Is she a kansai-ben speaker?)

Answer (score 1):

In conclusion.

- In this sentence, 「たまらない」 means something close to **"not acceptable"**.
- 「〜わ」 is so-called [お嬢様言葉/山の手の女言葉](https://osito.jp/minkana/yamanote.html).
  It's an expression that was used in some areas/social classes.

---

The verb 「〜{で|て}たまらない」 has the meaning of 「非常に～だ (it's very ~)」 attached to words that express the emotions and desires of the speaker.

「たまらない」 is written as 「堪らない」 in Kanji.
The Kanji 「堪」 used is expressed as 「堪える」 (kora-eru / ta-eru) and has some meaning like the example sentence

- 痛みを"我慢する": "Put up" the pain
- "堪忍する（許す）": Patience (forgive)
- 痛みに"耐え続ける": "Continue to endure" pain
- 空腹を"こらえる": "Stave off" hunger

Example sentences in the negative form:

- 空腹をこらえる。 <--> 空腹をこらえられない。
- 空腹にたえる。 <--> 空腹にたえられない。

---

> After giving a ride to a girl, a character says: 放課後 迎えに来っからよ
> Then the girl says: 冗談！ お顔と相談ね！ ちょっとバイクに 乗せてもらったからってたまりませんわ！

Since the girl says 「冗談！ お顔と相談ね！」, we can assume that she is refusing the invitation of a character.

Following the explanation of 「たまらない」 above, we can rephrase 「ちょっとバイクに 乗せてもらったからってたまりませんわ！」 as 「ちょっとバイクに 乗せてもらったからって（characterが迎えに来ることを）許せない（許容できない）わ！」(I can't allow a character to pick me up.).

---

reference
[コトバンクでの堪えるの解説 (Explanation of 堪える on コトバンク)](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E5%A0%AA%E3%81%88%E3%82%8B-502120)

Comment: Of course, 「たまらない」 is also used in the affirmation of exuberance, but it is not used in the context here.